# How to use the hint by the author to solve this exercise smartly? ("Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

The following exercise is from "Linear Algebra Done Right Fourth Edition" by Sheldon Axler.
We can download the electronic version of the book from the author's page:
https://linear.axler.net/
Professor Sheldon Axler, thank you very very much.

> Exercise 1B-8
> Suppose $V$ is a real vector space.
>
> - The *complexification* of $V$,denoted by $V_\mathbb{C}$, equals $V\times V$. An element of $V_\mathbb{C}$ is an ordered pair $(u,v)$, where $u,v\in V$, but we write this as $u+iv$.
> - Addition on $V_\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $$(u_1+iv_1)+(u_2+iv_2)=(u_1+u_2)+i(v_1+v_2)$$ for all $u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2\in V$.
> - Complex scalar multiplication on $V_\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $$(a+bi)(u+iv)=(au-bv)+i(av+bu)$$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $u,v\in V$.
>
> Prove that with the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication as above, $V_\mathbb{C}$ is a complex vector space.
>
> *Think of $V$ as a subset of $V_\mathbb{C}$ by identifying $u\in V$ with $u+i0$. The construction of $V_\mathbb{C}$ from $V$ can then be thought of as generalizing the construction of $\mathbb{C}^n$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$.*

1. For example, we need to prove that $(\lambda\mu) w=\lambda(\mu w)$ for all $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ and for all $w\in V_\mathbb{C}$.
   $\mu w$ is defined and $\lambda(\mu w)$ is defined and $(\lambda\mu) w$ is defined.
   If we look at the rule $(a+bi)(u+iv)=(au-bv)+i(av+bu)$ just symbolically, it is obvious that the associativity holds for the complex scalar multiplication on $V_\mathbb{C}$ because this rule is the same rule for the multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$ symbolically and we already know the associativity holds for the multiplication on $\mathbb{C}$ and $(ab)v=a(bv)$ holds for all $v\in V$ and for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
   I want to make this idea rigorous.
2. How to use the hint by the author to solve this exercise smartly?

Comment: You're right that in practice showing $(\lambda\mu)w=\lambda(\mu w)$ in $V_\mathbb{C}$ is very much the same as showing $(\lambda\mu)\nu=\lambda(\mu\nu)$in $\mathbb{C}$. However, I think the point of the exercise is to check the vector space axioms one by one, and to repeat the symbolic computation you mentioned again in the setting of $V_\mathbb{C}$. Also, the hint is not really a hint, Axler's just telling you how you should think about $V_\mathbb{C}$ intuitively.

Comment: @Don thank you very much for your answer.